# Ggplot2, where is my data?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am making a stacked area chart, but am not quite there.  I have followed previous posts and tried many iterations of the same code, with the same or worse results.  This is the most successful:

`ggplot(trtmeans, aes(x = year, y = dist, fill = factor(point))) + 
        geom_area(position = 'stack')+
        facet_wrap(~ trt)`

Here is the head of my dataframe:

```
   year trt  point     dist
  2009  C2   2.5  0.07819708
  2009  C2    10  0.24723689
  2009  C2  22.5  0.17690575
  2009  C2    45  0.28355538
  2009  C2    80  0.21410490
  2009  CC   2.5  0.09657976
```

and a link to the text file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/2m1bj970jj8rj7f/stackedplot.txt

and here is the result:

[image]

I don't have problems making this into a stacked barplot, but I would like to show it continuous over the years.  I didn't think it would be so hard.

And `dput(head(trtmeans))`:

```
structure(list(year = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("2008", 
"2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "(all)"), class = "factor"), 
    trt = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("C2", 
    "CC", "CCW", "P", "PF", "S2", "(all)"), class = "factor"), 
    depth = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L), .Label = c("5", 
    "15", "30", "60", "100", "(all)"), class = "factor"), point = structure(c(5L, 
    4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 5L), .Label = c("80", "45", "22.5", "10", 
    "2.5"), class = c("ordered", "factor")), mass = c(0.039049865125, 
    0.1215071878125, 0.084692273125, 0.147087857875, 0.110562685125, 
    0.0798292900625), coresum = c(0.5028998690625, 0.5028998690625, 
    0.5028998690625, 0.5028998690625, 0.5028998690625, 0.774738473875
    ), dist = c(0.0781970752917714, 0.247236893004015, 0.176905750464174, 
    0.283555383459544, 0.214104897780495, 0.0965797557709145)), .Names = c("year", 
"trt", "depth", "point", "mass", "coresum", "dist"), row.names = c(68L, 
70L, 72L, 74L, 76L, 79L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please supply the output of `dput(trtmeans)` in an edit of your question.

Comment: @joran: That's not the case: `geom_area` does require `y`.

Comment: @DavidRobinson Hrm. You're right. The documentation appears to be misleading on that point.

Comment: From your x axis labels it looks like `year` is a factor rather than a numeric variable. Is that the case?

Comment: I want year to be numeric since it is continuous (2009-2013).

Comment: @Nazer: of course you do, but it isn't, because in your file there are quotes around the year. You need to do `trtmeans$year = as.numeric(as.character(trtmeans$year))`

Comment: Hey!  I changed years to numeric and now it works!

Comment: @Nazer: Great, I thought it might. I posted that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `year` was a factor, not a numeric variable, which means the `geom_area` plot didn't connect the adjacent years. Convert it to a numeric variable with:

```
trtmeans$year = as.numeric(as.character(trtmeans$year))
```

The reason `year` was a factor is that it was in quotes in your original file:

```
"year" "trt" "depth" "point" "mass" "coresum" "dist"
"2009" "C2" "5" "2.5" 0.039049865125 0.5028998690625 0.0781970752917714
"2009" "C2" "15" "10" 0.1215071878125 0.5028998690625 0.247236893004015
"2009" "C2" "30" "22.5" 0.084692273125 0.5028998690625 0.176905750464174
```

Answer (score 0):

You need at least two points per x/fill/facet combination.  Consider:

```
trtmeans <- read.table(h=T, text="   year trt  point     dist
  2009  C2   2.5  0.07819708
  2010  C2   2.5  0.07819708
  2009  C2    10  0.24723689
  2010  C2    10  0.24723689
  2010  C2  22.5  0.17690575
  2009  C2  22.5  0.17690575
  2009  C2    45  0.28355538
  2010  C2    45  0.21410490
  2009  CC   2.5  0.09657976
  2010  CC   2.5  0.09657976")

ggplot(trtmeans, aes(x = year, y = dist, fill=factor(point))) + 
  geom_area(position = 'stack') + 
  facet_wrap(~ trt)
```

[image]

All I did was add 2010 points for various fill/facet values.

Comment: My full dataset does have additional years, but I don't get this kind of output with the same code.